# How do i find in which javascript any variable or function is declared?

Tags: javascript, debugging, web, google-chrome-devtools

I have N number of scripts included in a webpage, how do i find out which script is declaring variable X or which script is implementing function Y() ?

Kind of like linux's `which`/`type`

`root@mac:~$ which python
/usr/bin/python`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On any tab in Chrome's developer tools open the console by pressing Esc. In the new section that opens there's a Search tab. try putting your quoted search string e.g."var X"

e.g. ...

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work, it just prints the value... i am aware of chrome developer tools, i want to find out the origin of that variable/function... kind of link linux's `which/type`

Comment: Works for me if open dev tools on this site and search for var I get a list of files with a count of the number of matches in each file with the first one expanded showing each line of code with the match highlighted. Double clicking the line opens the file in the sources tab with the line highlighted.

Comment: what does `var _comscore` give ? in google chrome for mac it gives me "`undefined`", while typing just _comscore gives me actual value of that object

Comment: Not sure you're on the correct tab. I've added a picture for clarification

Comment: No problem. The console is only a REPL so will only evaluate what's entered. I don't believe you can anything more than try code examples to help you debug. :)